# Get value of key from all path of XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012, xquery

I have a xml

```
<EmployeeDetails>
    <BusinessEntityID>3</BusinessEntityID>
    <StoreDetail>
        <Sale>
            <AnnualSales>800000</AnnualSales>
        </Sale>
        <Sale>
            <AnnualSales>300000</AnnualSales>
        </Sale>
    </StoreDetail>
    <Revenue>
        <StoreDetail>
            <Sale>
                <AnnualSales>800000</AnnualSales>
            </Sale>
            <Sale>
                <AnnualSales>300000</AnnualSales>
            </Sale>
        </StoreDetail>
    </Revenue>
    <Report>
        <Sale>
            <AnnualSales>900000</AnnualSales>
        </Sale>
    </Report>
</EmployeeDetails>
```

I'm looking to find all values of `AnnualSales` from node `<sale>`. It can be under `EmployeeDetails-->StoreDetail-->Sale` or `EmployeeDetails-->StoreDetail-->Revenue-->Sale` or can be under some other tree. Is it possible to find all `sale` irrespective of path?

Currently i use below code and i get only for one path(2 rows)

```
SELECT 
    X.Y.value('(AnnualSales)[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') as AnnualSales
FROM test e
CROSS APPLY e.xml_data.nodes('EmployeeDetails/StoreDetail/Sale') as X(Y)
```

[DbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=f842bb7e8a4fdb21c4f48bca6a5a1171)

Expected Output:

```
800000
300000
800000
300000
900000
```

Comment: *"Currently i use below code and i get only one"* The above returns 2 rows, not 1.

Comment: Corrected. Thanks @Larnu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following.

Because XML structure is not consistent, we have to use the most inefficient XPath expression in the `.nodes()` method. And I am not sure about the correct data type for the returned values. IMHO, it could be `DECIMAL(x,y)`.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xmldata) VALUES
(N'<EmployeeDetails>
    <BusinessEntityID>3</BusinessEntityID>
    <StoreDetail>
        <Sale>
            <AnnualSales>800000</AnnualSales>
        </Sale>
        <Sale>
            <AnnualSales>300000</AnnualSales>
        </Sale>
    </StoreDetail>
    <Revenue>
        <StoreDetail>
            <Sale>
                <AnnualSales>800000</AnnualSales>
            </Sale>
            <Sale>
                <AnnualSales>300000</AnnualSales>
            </Sale>
        </StoreDetail>
    </Revenue>
    <Report>
        <Sale>
            <AnnualSales>900000</AnnualSales>
        </Sale>
    </Report>
</EmployeeDetails>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT c.value('(./text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS AnnualSales
FROM @tbl CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('//AnnualSales') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+-------------+
| AnnualSales |
+-------------+
|      800000 |
|      300000 |
|      800000 |
|      300000 |
|      900000 |
+-------------+
```